# Deleting old closed questions

Tags: discussion, deletion

While we are in the process of doing some cleaning on this site, what should we do about old questions that are closed and not deleted?

If I think they should be deleted should I vote to delete and flag for moderator attention?

What is the best practice to get attention to these questions in a way that will assist mods and the new [focus group](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/introducing-the-focus-group)?

Examples:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/771/is-school-education-necessary-closed

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-exactly-is-the-burden-of-proof

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7/why-did-the-randi-foundation-remove-the-1-million-dollars-prize

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/what-are-multiple-myelomas-differential-diagnoses-closed

Answer (score 3):

These questions have upvoted answers so they'd never automatically be deleted; this has to be handled manually.

(We have provisions for removing old 0 vote and negatively voted questions that have no significant activity over time, but that always precludes an actual *answer*.)

Thus I think the thing to do is what you are doing now, bring it up here.

The general philosophy of closing questions is that closure is a step on the road to eventual deletion; the main exception is duplicates where the other questions are needed as differently worded signposts to the eventual answer.

As for what should be eventually deleted, the criteria is simple:

> Does the existence of this page make the internet *better* or *worse?*

Though I would also add

> Does this existence of this question actively work against the charter of *this Q&A site?*

... as well.